# PDF document not updating to latest version on webserver - Cloudflare cache issue

Tags: pdf, webserver

I have updated a PDF file on my webserver via ftp several times but it is not updating to the latest version. Whenever I go to my website and open the document, it still shows the old document. I am using cloudflare service on my website which I suppose stores documents in cache but it has now been 2 weeks and it continues to show the old document. 
The file name has to remain the same.
Is there any workaround for this problem rather than changing the name of the file.

Comment: It could be possible that browser client is caching and showing the old copy of your file. You can try this quick hack. For instance, if the URL of your PDF is "http:// www.example.com/filename.pdf" then try removing the prefix "http:// www" from the URL (i.e., "example.com/filename.pdf") and query for the file. It would get the latest copy of your document.

Comment: I am afraid it is still the same. It is not just the case with my browser, I have tried to access it from many other computers and the result is still the same. To me it seems there is some issue with cloudflare as it stores files locally on its own servers worldwide and then delivers it to the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that it was actually an issue with caching at cloudflare. Cloudflare however has an option in their dashboard which can be used to purge the cache. This clears all the cache and updates the file or page to the latest version. The instructions are given at the link below.
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-

Comment: Just adding a quick note that changing files that we would cache would require purging the file or going to development mode. If you make changes to any of the file types listed at https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-, then that's when you want to purge it.